# debug error : max must have union class struct types

Tags: c++

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Sp
{ 
private :
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    Sp(int x = 0,int y = 0) : a(x), b(y) { };  

    int max(int x,int y);
};

int Sp::max(int a,int b) {  return (a > b ? a : b); };

int main()
{    
    int q,q1;
    cin >> q >>q1;
    Sp *mm = new Sp(q,q1);  
    cout << mm.max(q,q1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When extracting from a stream, you need to test the stream state (e.g., `if (!cin) { /* do error handling */ }`) after the extraction to ensure the extraction completed successfully.  If extraction fails, the value in the object is unchanged (and in this case, that means the object, `q` or `q1`, would be uninitialized).

Comment: Do not dynamically allocate when you don't need to. You're leaking memory, and in such a small example too. Also, why not just include `<algorithm>` and use `std::max`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of: `mm.max(q,q1);`
you need to use: `mm->max(q,q1);`
mm is a pointer and needs to be addressed as such.

Alternately, you could just say:

```
Sp mm(q,q1);  
cout<< mm.max(q,q1);
```

and avoid pointers all together.

Answer (score 1):

`mm` is a pointer to an `Sp`; you need to use `->`, not `.`:

```
cout << mm->max(q,q1);
```

However, it makes no sense to create the `Sp` object dynamically anyway; why not just:

```
Sp mm(q, q1);
cout << mm.max(q, q1);
```

As it is written now using dynamic allocation, you don't destroy the object that you created by using `delete`, which is an all-to-common programming error.